# Unwanted sorted behavior on result of vector-concatenation function

Tags: r, function, sorting, vectorization, operator-precedence

I apply a simple anonymous function to return c(x,x+5) on the sequence 1:5

I expect to see c(1,6,2,7,3,8,4,9,5,10) (the concatenation of the subresults) but instead the result vector is unwantedly sorted. What is doing that and how do I prevent it?

```
> (function(x) c(x,x+5)) (1:5)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

However applying the function on each individual argument is right:

```
> (function(x) c(x,x+5)) (1)
[1] 1 6
> (function(x) c(x,x+5)) (2)
[1] 2 7
...
> (function(x) c(x,x+5)) (5)
[1]  5 10
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting your question but the result seem as expected to me, due to + (and your function) operating on the whole x vector. To get what you want this works: unlist(lapply(1:5, function(x) c(x, x+5)))

Comment: @vodka: Great, please post as an answer. a) Does that vectorize efficiently? If not, might as well write a for-loop b) Is there no (vectorized) way to ensure the order of precedence is the function is applied to individual args first, then the subresults are concatenated?

Comment: To elaborate, when the input `x` is `1:5`, that gets concatenated with the `1:5+5`, so your output is `c(1:5,6:10)` . It's a matter of order of operation.

Comment: @Carl-Witthoft, yes I had already tagged it [tag:]operator-precedence based on vodka's comment. But I want to be able to control the precedence order here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this to spoof the order of operations:

```
foo<-function(x) {   
      bar<-cbind(x,x+5)  
      as.vector(t(bar))

}
foo(1:5)
```

Or in one line form:

```
(function(x) as.vector(t(cbind(x,x+5)))) (1:5)
```

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. I suspect `cbind` performance beats `lapply` for scalability.

Answer (score 2):

another approach:

```
bar <- function(x) {
    as.vector(matrix(c(x,x+5),nrow=2,byrow=TRUE))
}
```

Comment: `sapply(...)` also produces 5x2

Answer (score 2):

In this way it works:

```
   unlist(lapply(1:5, function(x) c(x, x+5)))
```